# How to add blink effect to complete table row using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have table structure like below, I am using PHP variable to store value, I want to add blink effect to complete row based on if the text contains in row is equal to PHP variable value then blink that row in green to some other color. I have tried below code but it only changes the background color of that cell only and not blinking effect to complete row. How to add blinking effect to complete row? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<title> Employee Data</title>

<?php

$empName = "Mr ABC";

?>

    <table id="emp_data" class="table table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Address</th>            
    </tr>
</thead>

    <tr>
        <td>20015</td>
        <td class='grn'>Mr ABC</td>
    <td>abc123@gmail.com</td>
    <td>1 st, Mumbai, IN </td>    
    </tr>
<tr>
        <td>20016</td>
        <td class='grn'>Mr XYZ</td>
    <td>xyz123@gmail.com</td>
    <td>1 st, Mumbai, IN </td>  
    </tr>
    </table>

</html>



<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#emp_data td.grn').each(function(){
        var empName = '<?php echo $empName; ?>';
            if ($(this).text() == empName) {
                $(this).css('background-color','#080');
            }
        });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use array for table data,

I used that, in below codes and handled in loop:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<title> Employee Data</title>

<?php

$empName = "Mr ABC";

$tableArray = array(
  [
    "id" => 20015,
    "name" => "Mr ABC",
    "email" => "abc123@gmail.com",
    "address" => "1 st, Mumbai, IN",
  ],
  [
    "id" => 20016,
    "name" => "Mr XYZ",
    "email" => "xyz123@gmail.com",
    "address" => "1 st, Mumbai, IN",
  ]
);

?>

  <table id="emp_data" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <?php

      foreach( $tableArray as $row ) {

        $blink = ( $row['name'] == $empName ) ? true : false;

     ?>

      <tr class='<?= $blink ? "blink" : "" ?>'>
        <td><?= $row['id']; ?></td>
        <td class='grn'><?= $row['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $row['email']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $row['address']; ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  </table>

  <style>
  .blink {
    color: #FF0000;
    animation: blinker 1s linear infinite;
  }

  @keyframes blinker {
    50% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
  </style>

</html>
```

Comment: Your welcome, of course. I added **red** color on blinking text. @ssbits

Comment: If this has helped you, please mark as answer. @ssbits

Comment: sure but..it worked on this sample, while implementing in script it not showing blinking effect ..though i am not getting any error..

Comment: Why you want to edit... Do you have another problem?

Comment: i am not getting output as expected

Comment: Okay, I see your scripts now, its very simple. just change your code ( css, background ) to this: `$(this).closest('tr').addClass('blink');` and use my css style in answer to effect blinking.

Comment: this changes  blinking all the rows.. actually i echo my tr like:  echo "<tr><td>{$name}</td></tr>"; in foreach loop, problem may be either class is not added or php variable value is not correctly parsed i am storing php variable value after str_replace some text in string.